# Get Teams Graph API id from bot framework request

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, bot-framework-composer

Bot framework `.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id` [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.teams.teaminfo?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) gives Ids in the format of `19:pmwblabla-DU6Cjf25Fblablabla@thread.tacv2`, but Graph API takes Ids in the form of GUIDs `1be44bc0-02cb-4715-9ecc-cba191e64cb5` [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request).

Graph API will return the "InternalId" which matches the Bot Framework, but how do I get the GUID from the Bot framework request?

I just want to do simple stuff like invite people to a team, create/delete teams/channels.

The Request to the server does not include the info, so `DialogContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().AadGroupId` is useless:

```
{
    "text": "<at>TestBot</at> help\n",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "text/html",
            "content": "<div><div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">TestBot</span> help</div>\n</div>"
        }
    ],
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2022-05-26T06:33:49.1002055Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2022-05-26T13:33:49.1002055+07:00",
    "id": "165354145676828864",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1d9mrAWL8cZKs3gp4Pasd8WD771EhsE1tlCs_MQn1Rb5QTmzk71GK934z8sxyHBE0eRFhWf-YslJXt_HdNDag",
        "name": "MyName",
        "aadObjectId": "guid-guid-guid-guid-guid"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "channel",
        "tenantId": "guid-guid-guid-guid-guid",
        "id": "19:eZWOxzVhYnXQasd07VtQVpdAHkgfP-7JyvcJR-0_w1@thread.tacv2;messageid=1653026739856"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:guid-guid-guid-guid-guid",
        "name": "TestMyBot2343456345656367"
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "mentioned": {
                "id": "28:guid-guid-guid-guid-guid",
                "name": "TestBot"
            },
            "text": "<at>TestBot</at>",
            "type": "mention"
        },
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "country": "US",
            "platform": "Windows",
            "timezone": "here",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ],
    "channelData": {
        "teamsChannelId": "19:eZWOxzasdasdasdHkgfP-7JyvcJR-0_w1@thread.tacv2",
        "teamsTeamId": "19:eZWOxzasdasdasdHkgfP-7JyvcJR-0_w1@thread.tacv2",
        "channel": {
            "id": "19:eZWOxzasdasdasdHkgfP-7JyvcJR-0_w1@thread.tacv2"
        },
        "team": {
            "id": "19:eZWOxzasdasdasdHkgfP-7JyvcJR-0_w1@thread.tacv2"
        },
        "tenant": {
            "id": "guid-guid-guid-guid-guid"
        }
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "localTimezone": "here"
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I thought I made it quite clear. DialogContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id gives an id like 19:pmwblabla-DU6Cjf25Fblablabla@thread.tacv2. Graph API requires GUIDs https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/GUID, any attempt to use the 19:.. gives an error that it requires a valid GUID.

Comment: Can you please use DialogContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().AadGroupId 
Ref Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.teams.teaminfo.aadgroupid?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Comment: {
"id": "19:pmwblabla-DU6Cjf25Fblablabla@thread.tacv2",
"name": null,
"aadGroupId": null
}

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I included the full request from teams to my server above.

Comment: @Cine-Are you looking for this-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-a-message-in-a-channel
In the channelIdentity section you will get the teams id as mention above-
"channelIdentity": {
        "teamId": "fbe2bf47-16c8-47cf-b4a5-4b9b187c508b",
        "channelId": "19:4a95f7d8db4c4e7fae857bcebe0623e6@thread.tacv2"
    },

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT that one still requires me to know the team guid, which is exactly what i am trying to get.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I found the solution, as you can see in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `DialogContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo()` only returns the information given from the payload, and the default from Teams is to NOT include the `AadGroupId`.

There is however an 'active' version of the same `await TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync(dc.Context)`. This will return the full object.

Comment: Thanks, [this helped me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74763507/1048572)!

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that this won't work from within the Bot Framework. It takes a real Teams App context, or the call will fail.